# C# ASP.net DropDownList returns null under IsPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this array:

```
public static string[] fooList = new string[] { "Foo", "Boo", "Coo" };
```

And then I make this drop down list:

```
fooDrp = new DropDownList();
                fooDrp.ID = "fooDrp"
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    fooDrp.DataSource = fooList;
                    fooDrp.DataBind();
                }
```

Then I tried to get the list item chosen:

```
string fooChoice = fooDrp.SelectedValue;
```

But fooChoice becomes `null`.
If I remove the `!IsPostBack` I only get the first value since the tabel is refilling. I am at a loss, been googling for a couple of hours and 90% of the info out there is just to use `!IsPostBack`. The rest is advanced database linking. Thoughts?

**Edit:** It seems I have been a bit unclear. I don't want to handle the case of getting a `null`. I want to know why I am getting `null` instead of the item I select in the list. At the moment I can't get anything from the list except the first value, which I get if I remove the `!IsPostBack`.

**Edit 2:** Maybe I need to give you the whole story then. This is an up and running webpage that is monitoring serveral services on several servers. It is displaying these in a table and have some buttons to stop and start these services.

I have been tasked to add some functionallity to it, among other things, to make it able to select and stop/start the specific services on every server instead of all of them at once. So i decided to add a drop down list for this. The list shows up, I can select an item, click the button, but then it crashes because `SelectedValue` returns `null`. Even though I selected an item in the list. The code is copy pasted, I have just changed the names to be easier to read.

Comment: Have you set selected value anywhere?

Comment: No, is that needed? the list always starts at the first value.

Comment: Does the fact that you are binding `servicesDrp` and getting the SelectedValue of `fooDrp` have anything to do with it? Why are those two different?

Comment: No that's just me missing to change all the names... will fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the source on every postback in the init event of the page.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Binding here
}
```

Then read the .SelectedValue or SelectedItem in the Page_Load, Button_Click or whatever method that comes at or after the load event.

If you don't use a bound datasource control(eg DataScource in the page itself) a controls ViewState will not be filled. The DataSource is responsible for that (eg caching). ViewState values are mostly state values of the control. A datasource has to be populated every time the page is rendered, unless the data is kept in the ViewState as well which is again the responsibility of the DataSource providing the data.

I could be wrong, it's been a long time for me since ASP.NET forms.

From what I remember is that WebForms can be simple as long as you follow this pattern of populating during init and doing logic in or after the load events.

---

Additional:
I overlooked what 'anonymous' is saying, you are indeed creating the control in your code, but by the looks of it you are not adding it to the page controls. Look whether you can add it to the aspx itself and then populate it or add it by using this.Controls.Add(fooBar) or this.Page.Controls.Add(fooBar). where this should refer to the Page instance.

Still the same principles as above apply. Good luck!

Comment: you sure this is an answer?

Comment: Maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: The thing is that this is an up and running website that I have been asked to add some functionallity to. I haven't done any of this before and google only goes so far. I actually have multiple dropdownlists for every row in a table. And are added to the table with  cell.Controls.Add(fooDrp).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fooDrp = new DropDownList();
                fooDrp.ID = "fooDrp"
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    fooDrp.DataSource = fooList;
                    fooDrp.DataBind();
                }
fooDrp.Attributes.Add("name", "fooDrp");
```

while initialize and read it as.

```
string value = Request.Form["fooDrp"];
```

Comment: Well even if I would get the empty string instead it doesn't really help since I need one of the list item for my code not to crash when I hit the button.

Comment: It seems I keep misleading you. I'm not interested in getting either null or the empty string. I want to get the value I have selected in the list. See edit of my original post.

Comment: where are you selecting item?

Comment: means you are adding it to web page? you should have wriiten that code

Comment: well, I have edited the original post. However its is alot of code and I dont know what is relevant since I'm only working on the functionallity in the .cs files. I have added some stuff already that is working fine but this dropdown just wont give me the selected element for some reason.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the issue lies somewhere else, since this doesn't work either... I guess I'll have to dig into the code even more.

Comment: The entire code i waaay too much to post here and I would need to rewrite most of it to not break security protocol because of server names and such. Also the whole webpage/project consists of almost 20 files with atleast 100 lines of code in each...